# Tkinter - Wait for several inputs before calculating the results

Tags: python, tkinter, button, wait

I am new to tkinter and python in general. I am trying to create a window that allows the user to input information (based on Entry and dropdown menus) and based on their choices, some new input will show up which will then be used to calculate the results. I've tried making a minimum reproducible snippet of code, as the original code is quite long.

The problem is that in the buttons I don't understand which command to include so that the program waits for all input before executing the rest of the code. Now it seems that no matter what I include it goes directly to the result part of the code.

I've tried having a function that saves the input and calculates the result as the command for the button, but it still does not wait.

The wait_variable as far as I understood only works for one variable?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1500x800")
Intro_Label = tk.Label(root, text = "Welcome") 
Intro_Label.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry_1 = tk.Entry()
entry_1.insert(0, 2.5) #default value
Label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="Input 1")

Label_1.grid(row=2, column=0)
entry_1.grid(row=2, column=1)

Label_2 = tk.Label(root, text="Input 2 ")
#Options for dropdown menu for transport method
I2_clicked = tk.StringVar()
I2_clicked.set("Choose from dropdown menu")
input2_opt = ["a", "b"]
input2 = tk.OptionMenu( root , I2_clicked , *input2_opt )

Label_3 = tk.Label(root, text="Input 2 ")
#Options for dropdown menu for transport method
I3_clicked = tk.StringVar()
I3_clicked.set("Choose from dropdown menu")
input3_opt = ["x", "y"]
input3 = tk.OptionMenu( root , I3_clicked , *input3_opt )

Label_2.grid(row=3, column=0)
input2.grid(row=3, column=1)
Label_3.grid(row=3, column =3)
input3.grid(row=3, column = 4)

def input_calculations():
    first_input = entry_1.get()
    if I2_clicked.get() == "a":
        if I3_clicked.get() == "x":
            entry_4 = tk.Entry()
            Label_4 = tk.Label(root, text="Input for x|a")
            entry_4.insert(0, 5) #dummy default value
            entry_4.grid(row = 4, column = 1 )
            Label_4.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

            entry_5 = tk.Entry()
            Label_5 = tk.Label(root, text="Second input for x|a")
            entry_5.insert(0, 4) #dummy default value
            entry_5.grid(row = 4, column = 4)
            Label_5.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

            #wait for both inputs before executing the calculations

            save_button = tk.Button(root, text ="Calculate results", command= )
            save_button.grid(row = 5, column = 6)

            #calculate some results
            result = float(entry_4.get())* float(entry_5.get())
        elif I3_clicked.get() == "y":
            entry_6 = tk.Entry()
            Label_6 = tk.Label(root, text="Input for y|a")
            entry_6.insert(0, 6) #dummy default value
            entry_6.grid(row = 4, column = 1 )
            Label_6.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

            entry_7 = tk.Entry()
            Label_7 = tk.Label(root, text="Second input for y|a")
            entry_7.insert(0, 7) #dummy default value
            entry_7.grid(row = 4, column = 4)
            Label_7.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

            entry_8 = tk.Entry()
            Label_8 = tk.Label(root, text="Third input for y|a")
            entry_8.insert(0, 8) #dummy default value
            entry_8.grid(row = 4, column = 6)
            Label_8.grid(row = 4, column = 5)

            save_button = tk.Button(root, text ="Calculate results", command= )
            save_button.grid(row = 5, column = 6)
            #wait for input before executing the next lines - what to insert here ?? 

            result = float(entry_6.get()) / float(entry_7.get()) * float(entry_8.get())
        
        #continues for all combinations (b and y, b and x) - different inputs, different calculations for each combo

        return result


btn = tk.Button(root, text="Confirm", width=15,command=input_calculations)
btn.grid(row= 10, column= 5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could link the buttons to functions that do the calculations.
Example function:

```
def button_pressed():
    result = float(entry_6.get()) / float(entry_7.get()) * float(entry_8.get())
```

You could either pass the entries as arguments in a lambda, or make the whole program inside of a class. This way every method can access all of the widgets.

For your save button you would then need to add the function to the command parameter:

```
save_button = tk.Button(root, text ="Calculate results", command=button_pressed)
```

You could make multiple functions / methods if you use a class to do the steps you need.